# c language fork process without wait for child process

Tags: c, fork, exec, wait

there is a question when I do the fork exercise in c language, it is very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// forkexec.c: fork then exec


int
main()
{
  int pid;

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){
    char *argv[] = { "echo", "THIS", "IS", "ECHO", 0 };
    execvp("echo", argv);
    printf("exec failed!\n");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("parent waiting\n");
    //wait(&status);
    //printf("the child exited with status %d\n", status);
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

the output is not as i expect:

```
root@Thomas-sun:~# ./a.out
parent waiting
root@Thomas-sun:~# THIS IS ECHO
```

how can it be? it seems it is still wait for user input after THIS IS ECHO, what a magic of wait! it will cause the program not running correctly! So could anyone explain a bit? thx

Comment: This is how processes works, they all execute independently of each other. It doesn't help that your parent process writes output that doesn't match the reality (it writes that it's waiting when it's really not).

Comment: When the parent exits, the shell displays the prompt, because the shell is just waiting for the parent. The shell doesn't know about or care about the child. The child continues to run (even after the parent exits), so its message get printed after the prompt. It might also happen that the child prints before the parent exits, in which case you'll see the child's message and then the prompt.

Comment: exactly, mate you saved my hours! before your answer, I was still struggling, now all is clear! thx!

Comment: So wait for the child to finish in this case will output correct format the print, otherwise, it will be confusing like in this case!